# Design very big PCB vs multiple parts w/ connector

Tags: pcb-design, connector

I'm working on a project which we need a long LED PCB (1,5m x 3cm) to bem inside a lamp tube. Currently we have small PCBs (around 20cm each) connected in series with exposed wires soldered by hands. We could also use a connector but it has to be cheap and also very small/slim not to affect the light effects inside the tube.

The other option would be to produce a single PCB for the tube. Is it possible to find machines that produce PCBs that big (for series production)?

If not, do you guys know good small connectors to put the boards together? We now need 8 wires between each board with <1A per wire.

I also thought of making the edge of the board with small pads so when putting the boards together one could sold them without wires. Is it possible?

Comment: Please don't ask open ended or opinion based questions. Or ask for shopping recommendations. This isn't a discussion based site, there are other sites for that. Please ask specific questions that can be answered with specific answers. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How is that opinion based? I want to know if it's possible to manufacture such a board because I can't find companies to do it.  Same for connectors that I usually only find big black ones. And also same for the last suggestion...don't know if that's physically possible in terms of production

Comment: Speak to PCB houses. I expect you'll get boards 0.5m long without trouble, so you only need to join 3 of them.

Comment: Well, we have access to all the same tools you do. We could go onto google and look up every board manufacturer OR you could do it. We could go onto digikey and look for connectors OR you could. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: Flex circuits can be any length typ 5m with LEDs on board on 8mm flex circuit.  These are standard 12V designs well stocked. why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @laptop2d, for that reason we all have access to the same internet with all the necessary material for virtually any subject of science. Therefore having a discussion forum is pointless. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: This is a Q&A fourm, its a little different that what your used to, the moderation system is designed to prevent discussion based questions.

Comment: http://makezine.com/2012/06/27/interview-laen-from-dorkbot-pdxosh-park-pcb/ "The largest panel size fabs generally deal with is 18×24 inches" which is slightly over 50cm in new money.

Comment: @TonyStewart, would you mind moving your comment to an answer to I can choose as an answer? I just found a company that makes flex circuits up to 5m with LED it here in my city

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex circuits can be any length typ 5m with LEDs on board on 8mm flex circuit. These are standard 12V designs well stocked. why reinvent the wheel?

There are literally hundreds of varieties now.

The solution is "12V Strip LEDs"

Answer (score 4):

The pads idea is completely workable - see "castellation" connectors. Make them slightly indented so there's somewhere for the solder to go. The limitation is that this is not at all flexible, so you have to fix the boards to a backing *before* you solder them. Or it'll self-destruct when you pick it up.

Comment: The backing must be very rigid indeed, the slightest bend or twist will rip the pads right off the PCB.